# upload file to firebase storage, Storage exception Object does not exist at location

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-storage

i'm trying to upload a pic to firebase storage, but it always gives an error
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
Object does not exist at location.
Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

```
private final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("upload");
//uploading pic to firebase storage
public void send(View view) {
        if (uri == null)
            return;
        StorageReference _storageRef = storageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getExtension(uri));

        _storageRef.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot ->
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                .addOnFailureListener(e ->
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fails", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

    }

 private String getExtension(Uri uri) {
        if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));
        } else {
            return MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new file(uri.getPath())).toString());
        }
    }
```

error message:
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
Object does not exist at location.
Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

firebase storage rule:

> allow read, write: if true;

Answer (score 0):

it was my mistake :), in firebase console i accidentally created a **firestore** server not a **firebase storage** server :)